# Using system time in nano-seconds as source of entropy in a smart contract

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, verifiable-random-function

I am working on a smart-contract to be deployed on ETH chain.

I am using an oracle(not the company!) system to get the information from off-chain (outside of the blockchain). Basically, we can think of the oracle as an API call which returns a random number. But for this api call I need a random seed.

Questions:

1. Can I use last few digits of system time (in nano or milli seconds) as the seed?
2. Since I don't really trust the randomness of the oracle provider, I would like to multiply the result of the random number with the system time again,

Does that make sense? Can the randomness of this number be used for encrypting sensitive data? Does that sound like a good idea?

P.S. Frequency of this call will be around 10 calls per minute.

Comment: Are you sure that the precision of the timer is really nano-seconds?  I'm really doubting it.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use last few digits of system time (in nano or milli seconds) as the seed?

That not a good idea:

- It's hard to tell with which accuracy an adversary could get to know your system time. Often it's openly disclosed by some process open to the outside (e.g. an https server, or log system). Best practice is to consider system time is not secret.
- The API to get system time in nanosecond often has a much coarser granularity. For example, on my Windows 10 machine, [`_timespec64_get`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/timespec-get-timespec32-get-timespec64-get1) always returns a multiple of 100 (thus 0.1 μs granularity).  And that's closer to the best case than from the worse: often that's millisecond, sometime second.
- Each decimal digit contains < 3.33 bit of information, thus 9 digits give at best < 30 bits of information, which is not enough for a key/challenge/nonce.
- Depending on environment, the problem of obtaining entropy is already solved in much more robust ways: [`/dev/urandom`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) (Unix/Linux), [`CryptGenRandom`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) (Windows), [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (Java), [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) (Python).

> Since I don't really trust the randomness of the oracle provider, I would like to multiply the result of the random number with the system time again.

It does make sense to *combine* several sources of entropy, but care must be exercised. *Multiply* is not suitable: e.g. if the oracle provider returns zero, then multiplying that with anything still yields the constant 0. One option for independent inputs is using a group binary operation, so that the combination is at least as good as the two inputs. The simplest possible group binary operation for combining independent entropy sources is [bitwise exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). There are better ways, including suitable for dependent entropy sources, see [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/217649).

> Can the randomness of this number be used for encrypting sensitive data?

For modern security, a symmetric encryption key should have 128 bit of entropy, and there's reason to believe we are short of that. More generally, I fear the question is indicative of insufficient knowledge to design a system requiring encryption.

Comment: Xor is only good to combine *independent* entropy sources. There are very few circumstances where it's a good choice. Instead, pass all the entropy as input(s) to a CSPRNG. Or at the very least through a key derivation function such as HKDF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do come from CS background, but you are right in assuming that I am new to this. 

I am working in blockchain VM environment, so I don't/can't have relay on OS for entropy.
I have access to an entropy provider, but I cant solely trust them, I need to add my pinch of salt to it. 
I am working in Windows SGX, so there is possibility of having private data. 
I don't know how to solve the granularity problem. I mean, an adversary with access to hw would be able to flood the processor to reduce granularity and increase odds of finding which 10 digits I chose.

Comment: @Marci-man: when I face similar problem of not trusting my entropy sources, I make several cryptographically conditioned sources taking care they are independent inasmuch as possible, and at the point of use XOR them, to have high insurance of the quality of the outcome. In your case, for this extra source of entropy you could use (part of a) 512-bit entropy pool, frequently updated by pool:=SHA-512(pool | source) where | denotes concatenation, and source is whatever source of entropy (system time, clock(), rdtsc,, QueryPerformanceCounter...) you can think of.